# Attempting to plot multiple graphs using `for` in R, but had to do call manually why? - troubleshooting explanation

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I was attempting to plot multiple boxplots to different variables of my data using a `for`. I am able to get the plots to be produced, but it only happens manually. So for instance I will execute the `for` loop and one graph will be created, then I have to do it again and again, etc. Which defeats the purpose of me making the `for` loop in the first place. I was wondering if this is a software behaviour or am I doing something wrong in my creation of the plots? Here is the code to reproduce things:

```
> dput(head(Job_Proficiency, 10))
structure(list(job_proficiency = c(88, 80, 96, 76, 80, 73, 58, 
116, 104, 99), T_1 = c(86, 62, 110, 101, 100, 78, 120, 105, 112, 
120), T_2 = c(110, 97, 107, 117, 101, 85, 77, 122, 119, 89), 
    T_3 = c(100, 99, 103, 93, 95, 95, 80, 116, 106, 105), T_4 = c(87, 
    100, 103, 95, 88, 84, 74, 102, 105, 97)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> for (i in seq(along = Job_Proficiency)){
+     with(data = Job_Proficiency, Boxplot(y = Job_Proficiency[i], xlab = names(Job_Proficiency)[i]))
+ }
```

So as stated before to produce the graphs, I have to execute the `for` loop manually. Is there a way to correct this? I had envisioned executing the `for` loop once and all five graphs would be produced.

EDITS: For clarification, I am using R-Studio as my IDE. I also used the `Boxplot()` function from the `car` package

Comment: Your `with` is not necessary. Also, try to print plot in loop: `print(Boxplot(...))`.

Comment: Seems the `with` was causing the issues. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using R-GUI, by default each iteration of the loop will be overwriting the plot display, so only the last one will be visible.
If using RStudio, all 5 plots will be created and you can navigate between them in the plot pane.

Or in case you want to see all five at once, you can use the `par` function to tell R to plot multiple charts side-by-side.

```
Job_Proficiency <- structure(list(job_proficiency = c(88, 80, 96, 76, 80, 73, 58, 
                                          116, 104, 99), T_1 = c(86, 62, 110, 101, 100, 78, 120, 105, 112, 
                                                                 120), T_2 = c(110, 97, 107, 117, 101, 85, 77, 122, 119, 89), 
                      T_3 = c(100, 99, 103, 93, 95, 95, 80, 116, 106, 105), T_4 = c(87, 
                                                                                    100, 103, 95, 88, 84, 74, 102, 105, 97)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
par(mfrow = c(1, 5))

for (i in seq(along = Job_Proficiency)){
      boxplot(x = Job_Proficiency[i], xlab = names(Job_Proficiency)[i])
}
```

`par(mfrow = c(1, 5))` basically tells it to plot the charts on a 1 row by 5 column grid.

Comment: I'm going to put it in my question, but I was using R-Studio. I did actually also use the `par()` function. I didn't think it would be relevant. But they only appeared once I did it one at a time. I just noticed it is because I used the `Boxplot()` function from the `car` package. But it should behave the same.

Comment: Is it not possible to navigate using the back/forward arrows in the plot pane? 

Can you confirm if you're using R's base `boxplot` function, or a function actually called `Boxplot`? Running your code with `boxplot` and changing the `y` to an `x` works fine. Also, I think the `with` call might not be needed.

Comment: it worked using R's base `boxplot()` actually. Just wondering if I could get the same behaviour using `Boxplot()` as well